# Is it impossible to perform initialization before calling a superclass's constructor?

Tags: java, xml

I'd like for a subclass of a certain superclass with certain constructor parameters to load an XML file containing information that I'd then like to pass to the superconstructor. Is this impossible to achieve?

Comment: Is the entire purpose of subclass is just to be able to construct with a super, or does it indeed extend super in more ways than that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using a factory method instead?  Maybe something like:

```
private MyObject(ComplexData data)
{
    super(data);
}

public static MyObject createMyObject(String someParameter)
{
    ComplexData data = XMLParser.createData(someParameter);
    return new MyObject(data); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the factory method be static?

Comment: Whoops, yeah.  Funny, you sound just like my compiler!

Answer (score 8):

You can call a static method in the super() call, e.g.

```
public Subclass(String filename)
{
    super(loadFile(filename));
}

private static byte[] loadFile(String filename)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Impossible, no.  Messy, potentially very.

I've needed to do this before and found that the easiest cleanest way and to handle it is to load the data before calling the constructor and then pass it as an argument.

Comment: +1 unless its your classes job to parse the XML, which in this case it doesn't look like it is

Answer (score 0):

I like the factory answer, but you can sometimes also do something like:

```
public MyObject(String parm) {
    super(parseComplex(parm));
}

private static ComplexData parseComplex(String parm) {
    ....
    return new ComplexData(...);
}
```

Comment: I feel using a factory is a bit of overkill here, if the purpose is just to be able to parse a ComplexData from XML (or anything else for that matter). So I think your approach is better. Do you actually prefer it over static method? Why?

Comment: The factory method is more flexible, it can work if you need to produce multiple arguments for the super() call as the result of your processing.

Answer (score 0):

I like mathews suggestion. A variation of this is to create objects that managed to preloaded data, and pass those into the constructor of the object.

I doing this in a project I'm working on for a client. Theres a bunch of configuration files that need to be loaded. I also have database and webservice connections that need to be established before dependent objects can be constructed.

It works great, its simple, and when someone else inherits this code it will be simple for them to follow the logic. This improves the value for the client.